# Is there any way to get smart sheet rows based on column value

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0

I want to use smart sheet api to read sheet data. my sheet has changedtm column. I want to fetch rows which are greater than certain date. is there any way to do this using smart sheet API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this kind of filtering via the Smartsheet API exactly. One approach would be you could do a [`GET Sheet`](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#get-sheet) request and use the `columnIds` query string parameter to provide the id number of the specific column you are looking to review. Then you would get back a response that only contained data for that specific column. The filtering based on the date values would then have to be done by you in your code.

If you will need other data in the rows I would then just do the `GET Sheet` request to get all of the data in the sheet and do the filtering of the response in your code.